# is common artifact to multiple Artifactory repositories stored only once?

Tags: artifactory

Artifactory is using storage based on checksum; So if i need to upload the same artifact in 2 artifactory repos; The artifact shall be physically stored only once to optimize footprint.
Is this applicable to any type of repo: especially generic and docker ?
in other words, if i have 2 registries configured in my artifactory, will image common to several charts be stored only once?
Brs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's stored only once for best efficiency and control, regardless of the repository type.

See the [official documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Checksum-Based+Storage) on how it actually works.